# Как сделать расстояние между ником игрока в чате и его сообщением?

Tags: php, html, javascript, css

Сам чат:

```
<iframe name='chatWindow' id='chatWindow' src ="iframe.php" width="1265" height="400"></iframe>   
<form action="iframe.php" method="post" id="form" target='chatWindow' >
<p>Сообщение:<input name="message" type="text" size="75" maxleght="255">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="OK">
```

А это iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout("window.location.reload()",15000); // Обновление раз в 15 секунд
</script>
```

и

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
      $message = $_POST['message'];
  }

  $db = mysql_connect("...", "...", "...");
  mysql_select_db("...", $db);
  if (trim($message) != "") {

      mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (message,username) VALUES ('$message','{$_SESSION['username']}')");
  }

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<br>";
      echo "{$row['message']}";
      echo $row['username'];
  }
?>
```

И скрипт к чату:

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#form").onsubmit(function (event) {
        var message = $("input[name='message']", form).value()
        if (message) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
    $("#form input[name='message']").bind('change keydown keypress', function (event){
        var text = $(this).value().replace(/^\s+/, "").replace(/\s+$/, "");
        $("#form input[type='submit']").prop("disabled", text == "");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<br>";
      echo "{$row['message']}";
      echo "&nbsp;".$row['username']; //&nbsp; - неразрывный пробел. 
  }
```

Это простейший вариант.
P.S. Вы с Владом не знакомы?